# Moment.Js - InvalidDate for Thai date format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using momentJs and creating date objects with it to perform validation if given date value is matching with locale and format or not.

When I create object with Moment() it gives Invalid Date.

Below is the sample code same as I am using in my application.

```
const dateStr = "วันศุกร์ที่ 30 มิถุนายน พ.ศ. 2566";
const formatStr = "ddddที่ d MMMM G yyyy";
const someday = moment(dateStr, formatStr, "th");
console.log(someday);
```

Output - `Invalid Date`

```
_d: Invalid Date {}_
f: "ddddที่ d MMMM G yyyy"_
i: "วันศุกร์ที่ 30 มิถุนายน พ.ศ. 566"
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: false
_isValid: false
_l: "th"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi 
Did you add moment-with-locales.js (Thai specific locale) ?

Comment: Input parameters have a fixed format. Please see [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) for more infomation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just import https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/locale/th.min.js after moment.js library and change `d` with `D` in `formatStr` variable to solve this error.

```js
const dateStr = "วันศุกร์ที่ 30 มิถุนายน พ.ศ. 2566";
const formatStr = "ddddที่ D MMMM G yyyy";
const someday = moment(dateStr, formatStr, "th");
console.log(someday);
const formattedDate = someday.locale("th").format(formatStr);
console.log(formattedDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/locale/th.min.js"></script>
```